# Entity Class not found PHPUnit Test

Tags: php, phpunit

Below are the paths where files are located,

```
src\TW\Talk\Entity\Talk.php
src\Tests\Talk\Entity\TalkTest.php
src\phpunit.xml.dist
```

In TalkTest.php, I have included PHPUnit and the entity Talk.

```
require_once 'TW/Talk/Entity/Talk.php';
require('PHPUnit/Autoload.php');

Class TalkTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    ...
}
```

In phpunit.xml.dist file, I have,

```
<phpunit>
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="TW">
      <file>Tests/Talk/Entity/TalkTest.php</file>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

I am running phpunit command from src directory, I am getting error that Fatel Error: Class 'Tests\TW\Talk\Enity\Talk' not found.

For reference, I am referring to php-object-freezer-master which has similar structure.

Any idea why the TalkTest is not able to find Talk class ?

phpunit command is trying to find Talk entity in Tests folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing phpunit.xml.dist to

```
<phpunit bootstrap="loader.php">
  <testsuites>
    <testsuite name="TW_Talk">
      <directory>Tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
  </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

and loader file as,

```
<?php

function tw_test_autoloader($class) {
    if(file_exists(__DIR__."\\" . $class . ".php"))
        require_once(__DIR__."\\" . $class . ".php");
}

spl_autoload_register('tw_test_autoloader');
```

Worked for me.

But still if I replace directory tag to file

```
<file>Tests\TW\Talk\Entity\TalkTest.php</file>
```

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your include_path:

```
echo get_include_path();
```

It should contain the directory to which your `TW/Talk/Entity/Talk.php` is relative. If it is not there, then you must add it either to `php.ini` or to PHPUnit's bootstrap.

You can easily test if PHP can find your file using your include path with this:

```
var_dump( stream_resolve_include_path('TW/Talk/Entity/Talk.php') );
```

Comment: phpunit command is trying to find entity under Tests folder. I have added "use TW\Talk\Entity\Talk;" It should ideally look for entity under Tests folder